# jQuery: Code works in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

The code below is supposed to sync the horizontal scrollbars of two iFrame.
It works in Firefox but does not work in IE.
In IE, it's not entering the ifr1.scroll() function.

```
<SCRIPT> 
$(window).load( function(){

  var ifr1 = $( $('#UserQueue_Header').contents() );
  var ifr2 = $( $('#UserQueue_Detail').contents() );

  ifr1.scroll( function(){      
     ifr2.scrollLeft(ifr1.scrollLeft());
  });

  ifr2.scroll( function(){
     ifr1.scrollLeft(ifr2.scrollLeft());
  });
});
</SCRIPT>

<iframe src="test.html" id="UserQueue_Header"></iframe>
<iframe src="test.html" id="UserQueue_Detail"></iframe>
```

Comment: -1. What doesn't work? What have you tried? Are you getting any errors? Please don't just post code.

Comment: "Code works in Firefox but not in IE" -- that's usually the case

Comment: @swatkins, except in this case. I'm surprised it works at all.

Comment: It's perfectly clear from the code sample what he means by "doesn't work." That code only does two things, and they're nearly identical to each other.

Comment: why not $(document).ready() instead of window.load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></SCRIPT>
```

```
$(window).load( function(){

  var ifr1 = $(window.frames[0]);
  var ifr2 = $(window.frames[1]);

  ifr1.scroll( function(){ 

     ifr2.scrollLeft(ifr1.scrollLeft());
  });

  ifr2.scroll( function(){

     ifr1.scrollLeft(ifr2.scrollLeft());
  });
});

<frameset>
    <frame src="test.html"/>
    <frame src="test.html"/>
</frameset>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the jQuery '$' variable twice.  For these lines:

```
 var ifr1 = $( $('#UserQueue_Header').contents() );
 var ifr2 = $( $('#UserQueue_Detail').contents() );
```

You need simply:

```
 var ifr1 = $('#UserQueue_Header').contents();
 var ifr2 = $('#UserQueue_Detail').contents();
```

Comment: No, that's so the OP doesn't have to do $(ifr1) and $(irf2) later on in the code.

Comment: The issue in IE is that it's not entering the ifr1.scroll() function.